# Cannot mount USB hard drive

Tags: finder, disk-utility, usb, mount

I have a 4TB USB hard drive (WB Elements) that I want to mount On a Macintosh Pro 16.

Unfortunately it cannot be mounted and the Mac does not show up any error messages. It also does not show up on "Disk Utility". This same hard drive mounts easily on a linux system and data can be accessed. What is puzzling is that I could mount it a few months ago.

On that same Mac, a 2TB USB hard drive could be mounted. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: is it connected with a USB cable?

Comment: Details please! If it mounts on linux get the partitioning details in Linux and post them to your question.

Comment: Share more details about partition type (APFS, NTFS, EXFAT, etc).
Do you have the chance to verify the disk can be mounted in other Mac?

Comment: The hqrd drive information is: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 7813965823, $MFT start cluster 786432, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 08ed8828fd882756d; containsMicrosoft Windows XP/VISTA bootloader BOOTMGR

Comment: Otherwise, yes it is connected by an USB cable. I have only one Mac to test it on.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 4 TB WD drive connected to my iMac running High Sierra (now Catalina) and it works fine. There is a 3rd party app named [Mountain](https://appgineers.de/mountain/) that will mount troublesome volumes (or it has for me). If you download from the developer site you get a free trial period. Should be worth a try.